# mvc select second table data using linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

/*
hallo, I am  new in mvc and linq. I've 2 table in relation many to many: 1)employe 2)device

Selecting an employe I'd like to see his devices:

-Marco
-Franco
Selecting Marco should appear the devices associated to him.

My code (not work):

Controller:
*/

```
public ActionResult VediDevice(int id)
        {
            Impiegato impi = new Impiegato();

            List<Device> ListDevice = new List<Device>(); 

            using (DatabaseMVCCOntrolsEntities db = new DatabaseMVCCOntrolsEntities())
            {
              ListDevice= db.Devices.Where(u => db.ImpiegatiDevice.Any(m => m.impiegatiID == id)).ToList();  <---???

             }






             return View(ListDevice);

}
```

VediDevice.cshtml:

```
@model List<MVCControlToolkit.Models.Device>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VediDevice";
}

<h2>VediDevice</h2>

<table class="table table-striped  table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            NOME
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Not work.

What should I do?

Thank you

Ale

Comment: the solution:ListDevice = db.Devices.Where(u => u.ImpiegatiDevices.Any(m => m.impiegatiID == id)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Use Include before where

```
ListDevice= db.Devices.ToList().Where(u => u.item.Any(m => m.impiegatiID == id)).ToList();
```

and add your Device class

```
List<ImpiegatiDevice> item{get;set;}
```

Comment: Get the same result: All the list of the device….. But I need  just the list of the device of the emplyee selected.

Comment: Did you have List<ImpiegatiDevice> in Device class

Comment: Give me  this error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Membro di tipo specificato 'item' non supportato in LINQ to Entities. Sono supportati solo inizializzatori, membri di entità e proprietà di navigazione di entità.'

Comment: Sorry db.Devices.ToList()
t with uppercse

Comment: not  work: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Il valore non può essere null.
Nome parametro: source'

Comment: The solution:ListDevice = db.Devices.Where(u => u.ImpiegatiDevices.Any(m => m.impiegatiID == id)).ToList();